# How to use unmunch command of hunspell?

Tags: hunspell

The project link : https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell/

I have followed the instructions and compiled the DLL files on windows 8.1

Here the dll files folder

[image]

Then i start a CMD window as administrator

Move to that folder and run this command

```
unmunch.exe tr.dic tr.aff >> asdas.txt
```

It gives the below error at the end when trying to write to a file i guess

[image]

How can i solve this problem? I also need output file to be encoded as UTF8

Ty

Comment: Did you succeed to resolve your issue?

Comment: @orghu I really cant remember :D